# Application stops running after upgrading to PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php-5.3

I just got my dev box upgraded from php 5.1.6 to php 5.3.3 (LAMP) and my application stops working. I dont know what is wrong, but `index.php` doesn't load completely. The actual code which loads the data got commented (when I check using 'inspect element'). I dont see any specific errors in error and access logs. Do I need to make any changes to code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, I figured out that the reason my php was failing is in my script I had `<?` instead of `<?php`. Can somebody please confirm if `<?php` notation is mandatory from PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to look at the migration guides as there were quite a few backwards incompatible changes in 5.3.

- [PHP 5.1.x to 5.2.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php)
- [PHP 5.2.x to 5.3.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php)